# how to set up ckfinder for ckeditor with ( React.js / django /django rest framework )?

Tags: django, reactjs, ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm trying to create a web app for my final school project and i decided to use CKEditor5 to create rich test posts  i managed to integrate Ckeditor with Django and, i can successfully create post from the admin aria and add images  but when i wanted to do the same thing from the frontend (react), i faced some problems that i didn't know how to solve .

so when i try to upload an image i recive a popup in the browser with the message ** can't upload the file **

this is my code for the editor (it works just fine with text )

```
<CKEditor
              editor={ClassicEditor}
              data=""
              onInit={(editor) => {
                // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                console.log("Editor is ready to use!", editor);
              }}
              onChange={(event, editor) => {
                const data = editor.getData();
                this.setState({ content: editor.getData() });
              }}
              onBlur={(event, editor) => {}}
              onFocus={(event, editor) => {
                console.log("Focus.", editor);
              }}
              config={{
                ckfinder: {
                  // Upload the images to the server using the CKFinder QuickUpload command.
                  uploadUrl: "http://localhost:8000/media/uploads/",
                  options: {
                    resourceType: "Images",
                  },
                },
              }}
            />
```

the url path that i but in the uploadUrl is the path where i put media when using the admin ckeditor that i integrated sepreatly i followed i tutorial to do it

this is the variables  that i set in the sittings file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'


CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
```

so i think that i should not use the same path because i can not POST to this url i get in the local host console an error

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /media/uploads/
[22/May/2020 08:26:49] "POST /media/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2513
```

(i don't use react-create-app server i'm loading react as a django  frontend app in port 8000 )

Comment: This message Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /media/uploads/
 means that the csrf token is missing in your post request, where is it by the way on your code ?

Comment: i though that the ckfiender handles it by default because i didn't find how to add it in the docs ,

Comment: i added it just in the post  Redux action for the whole post using axios

Comment: but for this image upload i don't know how to add it

Comment: add those headers to the file where you are making the axios call after importing axios axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';

Comment: `axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';`
`axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';`

Comment: Okey i see the post actually is handled by ckeditor

Comment: i already did but it didn't work

Comment: yes the editor handles the upload on his one but i don't know how to add the token

Comment: is there an other way (maybe not using the ckfinder ) to upload images to ckeditor

Comment: i will try to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

After searching, the solution is that you pass the csrf_token within the headers of your request

So here we need to get first the csrf_token from django session and then pass it to the server

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

The function above will get extract the csrf_token so you can call it and store it in a const

```
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

and then you add the headers to your call

```
    uploadUrl: "http://localhost:8000/media/uploads/",
    options: {
        resourceType: "Images",
    },
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrftoken,
    }
```

try that and let me know if that does not work.

As an alternative your can try to wrap your function with the decorator for csrf_exempt to see first is that will work, import it first

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt 
def my_view(request):
```

Comment: i got an error `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` and the page didn't  load

Comment: i tried importing jquery but im'not sue if i did it the right way

Comment: i got rid of the error but it didn't work the same error as before

Comment: `urlpatterns = [ ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` for the uploadUrl

Comment: try the solution provided in my updated answer, we will see if that work so we can continue to troubleshoot the issue

Comment: i try it but it didn't work i think that the django media path it's not compatible with such operation i think that i should create an other server to serve media files , what you think ?

Comment: maybe because you are trying to upload the file without passing by a view, did this url /media/uploads/ point to a view ?

Comment: what should the view return

Comment: maybe this is the problem, the server is refusing connection for some reason, first lets change this url and delete the http://localhost:8000/ and keep only /media/uploads/ because we are uploading from the same server, and then if it will not work we will try to create a view that will handle the image file and store it in the server

Comment: okey now change the media root to that  MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Comment: i tried adding ``if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    ] ``

Comment: okey lets create a view that will point to the url /media/uploads/ and we will print the request.method at the first place to be sure that is a post request